# "Kids is mean" or "kids are mean"?

Tags: irregular-plurals

Which one is correct?

"Kids is mean" or "kids are mean"?

I saw the first one in Ghostbuster's subtitle on netflix, and was wondering why would it be correct if **Kids** is plural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character that speaks that line, Patty Tolan, is speaking African American Vernacular English (AAVE), not Standard American English.

One notable feature of AAVE is:

> The verb *be* has two forms in the singular: first person *am* (reducible to *'m*), and non-first person is (reducible to nothing with subjects other than it; reducible to *'s* with it).
>
> https://public.wsu.edu/~gordonl/S2003/326/SAE_AAVE.htm

In plainer language, in AAVE, *to be* is conjugated like this:
I am
You is
He/she/it is (or nothing, e.g. "He fast")
We is
You is
They is

So, "kids is mean" looks like very typical AAVE.

Comment: _I is_ also exists in AAVE, though contracted _I’m_ is definitely more common.

Comment: Of course, it's a mistake to presume that AAVE is a single dialect.  It encompasses a range of possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the research @Juhasz. However, I'm wondering why they would use AAVE in a new American movie. Is this normal in America?

Comment: @RicardoMartins, AAVE is not an old dialect. It's the way English is spoken today by large numbers of black people in America.